# is it correct to give out the uuids to the web application

Tags: spring, rest, api, uuid

is it common to have URLs like:

```
host.com/article/d94d09b9-32f0-4a94-86a9-d756468c058d
```

A colleague told me that it's dangerous to send uuids to frontend, because they are primary keys of the tables. So the "hackers" have more information about your data structures.

Is that correct? And if its not good, i would still need an unique identifier for my URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I use UUIDs as my public facing identifier and still keep my sequence id for data integrity. This make it so you can't change the id on the url to the next number ex (2 to 3) and possible get access to the next recored.

```
host.com/article/d94d09b9-32f0-4a94-86a9-d756468c058d
```

This is my preferred way.

Comment: One thing to note I store my UUIDs as Binary so your not indexing on a String.